# Android saving nested Objects structure

Tags: android, object, save, sharedpreferences, gson

i am developing an app for android, and I have parsed data from website. I need to save the whole "**rozvrhy**" List with everything it contains (see below) in the phone so it can be loaded next time user starts the app:

Data I need to save are in the following structure:

```
List<Rozvrh> rozvrhy = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Multimap<String, Hodina>> rozvrh = new HashMap<>();
```

where **Rozvrh** looks like this:

```
public class Rozvrh {

String trida;
Map<String, Multimap<String, Hodina>> rozvrh;
List<String> dny;
List<String> hodiny;
}
```

and **Hodina** class looks like this:

```
public class Hodina {

String predmet;
String zkPredmet;
String vyucujici;
String zkVyucujici;
String ucebna;
String zkUcebna;
String den;
String hod;
}
```

I tried to use Gson but it cuts out the actual Hodina objects in Map. Is there any easy solution how to this? Or is better to use SQLite? - However I have no experience with databases... :/

Thank you for any possible tips!

Comment: Check this out, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: Better to Use database.

Answer (score 0):

```
I need to save the whole "rozvrhy" List with everything it contains (see below) in the phone so it can be loaded next time user starts the app:
```

Since you have said that, i would recommend to use SQLite for your application. You can parse the response and insert it to the SQLite Database.

Therefore, you can use the advantages of a database to query the required data and it would be the best solution.

Android SQLite is too simple to implement. You can start with this. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Alright I am gonna to learn something about it, thank you for your advice. Is it better to fill that database yet during the parsing, or I can use advantage of what I already have and somehow fill it in from my structure?

Comment: @Hokyjack Data parsing and insertion to database can occur at the same time or later depending on your requirement. But it should happen in different threads.